# Trading view charting library week start by default from Monday I want to change it to Sunday

Tags: javascript, reactjs, trading, tradingview-api

I am using the trading view charting library and the issue is that all of the stocks are Saudi Arabian so in Saudi Arabia week starts on Sunday, and in the library, the week begins on Monday so when I click on weekdays from the tab, the footer show day begins from Monday.

I changed the time zone to "Asia/Riyadh" by using the provided setTimezone() method, but it just changed the time zone of the library my problem is still there.
I tried to find the method but all useless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the session inside the SymbolInfo object:

```
const symbolInfo = {
            ticker: 'BTC',
            name: 'BTC',
            description: 'BTC',
            type: 'crypto',
            //session: '24x7',
            session: '1;1030-1415:12345',
```

- 1 : Trading Day starts from Sunday
- 1030-1415 - Trading activity time
- 12345 - 5 days from sunday till thursday

Comment: do i have to add this in backend?

Comment: i am still stuck there

Comment: You have to use this inside "resolveSymbol" method of Datafeed API. Please use following reference: https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/connecting_data/Datafeed-API/#:~:text=Datafeed%20API%20is%20a%20set,provide%20data%20to%20the%20library.

Comment: It did not work but I changed the symbol in the backend and then it worked for me